# Button gradient not working when added to viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I am adding a button gradient using the below code

```
extension UIView {
    func applyGradient(colors: [UIColor]) {
        self.applyGradient(colors: colors, locations: nil)
    }

    func applyGradient(colors: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
        gradient.locations = locations
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Calling `initStyle()` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is not working.

```
func initStyle() {
    submitBtn.applyGradient(colors: [#colorLiteral(red: 0.1176470588, green: 0.3882352941, blue: 0.5254901961, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.2941176471, green: 0.9098039216, blue: 0.9529411765, alpha: 1)])
    submitBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    submitBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

I am creating all UI elements programatically. I had constraints setup properly and is working.

```
lazy var submitBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.setTitle("SUBMIT", for: .normal)
    return btn
}()
```

How to make this working?

---

The gradient display only if I place `initStyle()` in `viewDidAppear()` and not in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, which is creating a delay in displaying the button gradient. I want to avoid this delay. So I am adding it in viewDidLayoutSubviews, but then the gradient does not appear.

Comment: You are passing location nil and x,y position is zero and check frame ..check gradient code

Comment: The gradient display only if I place `initStyle()` in `viewDidAppear()` and not in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, which is creating a delay in displaying the button gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that self.bounds is 0 at the point you are calling your gradient function. Try calling it at a later time, for example viewWillAppear or call view.layoutSubViews to trigger iewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: Test it out by printing self.bounds

Comment: I manually set the button frame `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)`, event though layout constraints are added and `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `false` makes this work.

Comment: I am not sure why the bounds are 0 when the constraints are set.

Answer (score 0):

```
lazy var submitBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .custom) //Set custom instead of system
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.setTitle("SUBMIT", for: .normal)
    return btn
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the function inside
    viewWillAppeare()

Also why not apply the gradient into the button from the start without a separated function? that will make the button appears w\ the gradient already builtin.

if you want to set the gradient w\ a condition you could use the following

```
func displayButton(condition: Bool){


lazy var submitBtn: UIButton = {
let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
btn.setTitle("SUBMIT", for: .normal)

if condition == true {
//set the gradient here
return btn
} else if condition == false
return btn
}

}()



override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()
 //here you can set the condition to show the gradient or not depending on what you want
displayButton(true) //will show the gradient
displayButton(false) // will show without gradient

}
```

I can't test this code at the moment so i'm not sure about it, give it a try.